# 「こんなに」と「こんな風に」difference?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, nuances

As far as i'm aware, both me to "this kind of" or "like this" but what is the difference. I was talking to someone but they said that **「こんな風に」** is more natural, the original sentence was **「こんなに見えなければイギリスではない」** with a picture of my my slightly flooded driveway.

my original sentence:

> こんなに見えなければイギリスではない

corrected sentence:

> こんな**風**に見えなければイギリスではない

what i wanted to say in english:

> if it doesn't look like this, it's not britain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1)「こんなに見{み}えなければイギリスではない。」 (Your original)
>
> 2)「こんな風{ふう}に見えなければイギリスではない。」 (Corrected)

Between those two sentences, 2) is considerably better than 1) if you want to say:

> "If it doesn't look like this, it's not Britain."

「風に」 can be replaced by 「感{かん}じに」 with no problems.

Is 1) totally out of the question, then?  I would say no because ***very informally***, some native speakers might say it, too.  But still, it would not be something you should be taught to say as a Japanese-learner.

I would like to stress, however, that in the particular situation/context of ***showing a person a photo***, there would be little misunderstanding even if it were 1) that you actually uttered.

As a stand-alone sentence without further context, however, 1) could sound fairly ambiguous.

Finally, I have no intention of changing the purpose of your question, but if I could express the idea in question freely as a native Japanese speaker, I would not even use 「見える」, to be honest with you.  You used it simply because you had a sentence in mind in English that used "to look".  Your sentence was translated; Mine will come directly from a Japanese-speaking brain without translation.

I would use 「なる」 and say something like:

> 「こんな風に**なっていなければ**イギリスではありません。」 or
>
> 「こんな風に**ならなければ**イギリスではありません。」

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I very much appreciate all the extra information you gave me and how you would say it!

Comment: Interesting, but why would you use なる here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use:

> *こんな風に*見えなければイギリスではない

which gives a nuance of, "If it didn't look *like this*, it's not Britain."

Your original sentence:

> *こんなに*見えなければイギリスではない

gives me the nuance of, "If you couldn't see *this much*, it's not Britain."